# Display all duplicated values and their IDs from a table (SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I'm using SQL Sever.
I have a table that looks like this:

```
+---------+--------------+
| ID         Name        |  
+---------+--------------+
| 1       | John   
| 2       | Charles  
| 3       | Molly  
| 4       | John
| 5       | Kathy
| 6       | Mike
| 7       | Charles
| 8       | Kathy
```

Is there a way I can retrieve all the duplicated values only? Not just one of them, but all.

This is the desired output:

```
+---------+--------------+
| ID         Name        |  
+---------+--------------+
| 1       | John     
| 4       | John
| 5       | Kathy
| 8       | Kathy
| 7       | Charles
| 2       | Charles
```

Comment: Learn Group By, Count, Having.
What Database Server you use?

Comment: Please update your question with the RDBMS you are using.

Comment: Question updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works in SQL Server.

```
SELECT Id, Name
FROM MyTable AS T1
WHERE
    EXISTS
    (
        SELECT Name
        FROM MyTable
        WHERE Name = T1.Name
        GROUP BY Name
        HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if this helps.

```
SELECT t0.ID,t0.Name
FROM @YourTable t0
INNER JOIN (SELECT
           Name, COUNT(*) AS CountOf
           FROM @YourTable
           GROUP BY Name
           HAVING COUNT(*)>1
           ) 
t1 ON t0.name=t1.name
```

Answer (score 0):

It works for SQL Server:

```
select t.ID, t.Name
from
(select ID as 'ID', 
       Name as 'Name',
       row_number() over (partition by Name order by Name asc) as 'rn'
from table ) t
where t.rn > 0
```

Comment: Could you add some explanation of why this snippet works?

Comment: Sure, I use window function for ranging names. But i have to wrap my query and then apply filter condition "t.rn > 0", in other way my query wouldn't be work. 
I used this kind of technique that to delete all duplicate row  and save only one row. It works well, when you don't have any id, only name field.  I am sure that it works for mssql, but windows functions could be quite hard, if we use them for huge amount of rows.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend using `exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.name = t.name and t2.id <> t.id);
```

With an index on `(name, id)`, this should have the best performance.